# Morris charts & PHP issues

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json, morris.js

I'm struggling with Morris charts for some time now. I'm trying to call data from Mysql table using PHP code but keep getting this error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

But when I inspect site I see that I got json so I believe that encoding was successful

```
    Morris.Bar({
    element: 'brojLampi',
    data: [{"label":"Mali Tabor","value":"5"},{"label":"Prišlin","value":"24"}]*//output*,
    xkey: 'naziv_naselja',
    ykey: 'broj',
    labels:['naziv_naselja'],
    });
```

Here is PHP code:

```
<div id="morris-area-chart"></div>
<?php
try {
    $db  = connectPDO();
    $row = $db->prepare("SELECT naziv_naselja, count(naziv_naselja) AS broj FROM v_rasvjeta GROUP BY naziv_naselja");
    $row->execute();

    $json_data = array(); 
    foreach ($row as $rec) { 
        $json_array['label'] = $rec['naziv_naselja'];
        $json_array['value'] = $rec['broj'];
        array_push($json_data, $json_array);

    }
?>
    <div id="brojLampi"></div>
    <script type="application/javascript">
    Morris.Bar({
    element: 'brojLampi',
    data: <?php
    echo json_encode($json_data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
?>,
    xkey: 'label',
    ykey: 'value',
    labels:['Name']
    });

    </script>
    <?php
    closePDO($db);
} 
catch (PDOException $e) {
    showPDOErrors($e, $db);
}
?>
```

Even, I tried something like this but it didn't work

```
$.getJSON("brojLampi", function (data) {    
Morris.Bar({
element: 'brojLampi',
data: <?php echo json_encode($json_data,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE)?>,
xkey: 'naziv_naselja',
ykey: 'broj',
labels:['naziv_naselja'],
});
});
```

I got this error when using code above:

```
GET http://localhost:8081/APLIKACIJE/RASVJETA/stranice/brojLampi 404 (Not Found)
```

Any help would be appreciative :)

Comment: Do not post the errors as screeshots, please. They are not searchable. Copy and paste then instead.

Comment: Thx, Ill keep that in mind for next problem :)

Comment: You can also edit your question, make it better and you'll probably attract more people to help you.

Comment: Where is "length" condition which has been applied by you?

Comment: Length condition is applied to morris.js script  if that's what you are asking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using code from question above I found solution to my problem (quite funny)

```
    <div id="brojLampi"></div>
    <script type="application/javascript">
    Morris.Bar({
    element: 'brojLampi',
    data: <?php
    echo json_encode($json_data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
?>,
    xkey: 'label',
    ykey: 'value',
    labels:['Name']
    });
```

It was a problem in this line, instead of this:

```
 ykey: 'value'
```

I just added brackets and it worked

```
ykey: ['value']
```

Funny, I know :) Hope it helps